# How to get value and use if XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to use if statement and get value and I don't know how to use it. I need get 'IN STOCK' in case value of 'term' equal "7 - 14 dni"

```
<xsl:term>
<xsl:value-of select="termin_realizacji" />
</xsl:term>
<xsl:if test="term ='7 - 14 dni'">
<xsl:element name="g:availability">
    <xsl:text>in stock</xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:element name="g:avai">
 <xsl:value-of select="termin_realizacji" />
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**: 
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you change

```
     <xsl:if test="//term = '7 - 14 dni'">
```